# BroadcastReceiver doesn't work accurately unless registered Manually

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

To put it simply; `BroadcastReceiver` **Works** when defined in `Manifest` but it works with a short **Delay** and it doesn't **Always** trigger unless Registered **Manually**.

Here is the `BroadcastReceiver` I created to capture event when date changes (day is passed):

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        switch (intent.getAction()){
            case Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK:
            case Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED:
            case Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED:
            case Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED:
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", intent.getAction().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here registered in **Manifest**, It works but has a short delay and also doesn't always trigger:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receivers.BootBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But when registered **manually** via my background service it works just fine:

```
public class ApplicationService extends Service{

    ...

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        registerReceiver(new BootBroadcastReceiver(), intentFilter);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

To investigate this issue further I created two **similar** app which in one `BroadcastReceiver` registered in **Manifest** and in the other one receiver is registered **Manually** via `Service`.

In the **Manifest** one all events are triggered few second after **Manual** one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was hidden in Intent [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_TIME_TICK):

> ACTION_TIME_TICK Added in API level 1
>
> public static final String ACTION_TIME_TICK
>
> Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. You
> cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by
> explicitly registering for it with
> Context#registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter).

To simply put, you can't receive `TIME_TICK` through registering the `BroadcastReceiver` in **manifest**, it has to be registered in your application **components** (Service, Activity, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<receiver android:name=".Receivers.BootBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Tried this before but is't not working, receiver by default is enabled and the exported does't change anything ><

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can have multiple each one having its action.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

The documentation says that "An app component should declare separate filters for each unique job it can do." This would allow finer grained detail for different actions

Comment: Actually this receiver do a single unique job. Even though it have multiple filters, the receiver do a same job for all the intent it receives.

Comment: Sadly even defining a separate filter for each action doesn't solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Define a BootBroadcastReceiver  anywhere in Activity/Fragment like this:

```
mBootBroadcastReceiver = new BootBroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.d(TAG," BootBroadcastReceiver"); //do something with intent
   }
 };

mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter("action_name");
```

Now register the BootBroadcastReceiver in onResume() and Unregister in onPause()

```
       @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            registerReceiver(mBootBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            if(mReceiver != null) {
                unregisterReceiver(mBootBroadcastReceiver);
                mBootBroadcastReceiver = null;
            }
            super.onPause();
        }
```

**add permission in your Manifest.**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: I dont have a problem registering BroadcastReceiver manually, Please Read the question carefully...